# How to filter jQuery code on different html ID's

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery file where I want to make a loop to see which html ID is present on the page.

I've written an "if" structure but I was woundering if it could be done more elegant.

```
if ($("#ID1").length) { // if Selector Element exists
    myFunction1;
}else{
    if ($("#ID2").length) { // if Selector Element exists
        myFunction2;
    }else{
        if ($("#ID3").length) { // if Selector Element exists
            myFunction3;
        }else{
            if ($("#ID4").length) { // if Selector Element exists
                myFunction4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I could use a "switch" but since it is the selector I am querying on it wont work.

Thanks
Flemming

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Side note: The blocks separating an `else` and an immediately following `if` aren't required, and it is a common practice to skip the block so you don't have as much nesting. `} else if (condition) {`

Comment: I'm trying to see what ID is present on the page and then run the function related to that specific ID.

The reason is that my page does not always the same ID's.
The order of the filter is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an array of ID's and an associated object for the functions would simplify this:

```
var funcs={
  ID1: myFunction1,
  ....
  ID4: myFunction4
}
var selectors =['ID1',...'ID4']
```

Then iterate array and call appropriate function

```
$.each(selectors, function(_, id){
   if($('#' + id).length){
     funcs[id]();
     // use "return false;" if you want to break the loop here when one is found
   }
});
```

As per comment by JonathanLonowski can reduce to simply iterating the object keys and getting rid of array

```
$.each(funcs, function(id, func){
  if($('#' + id).length){
     func();
  }
});
```

Comment: If the order doesn't necessarily matter, the iteration could be over `funcs` directly. Each function would be available from the arguments – `$.each(funcs, function (id, func) { if (...) { func(); } })`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of id to function mapping as suggested by @charlietfl.

```
 var funcs={
    ID1: myFunction1,
    ....
    ID4: myFunction4
 }
```

And find any of the id using multi selector as follows,

```
 $("#ID1,#ID2,#ID3").each(function(){
   func[$(this).attr(id)]();
 });
```